# Commands starting with "%" and "-" characters

Tags: python, command

I've seen these in books and over the internet but never understood them. Something like this

```
...modify changer.py without stopping Python...
% vi changer.py
```

and

```
python -mtimeit -s
```

What do they mean? And where are they applied?

Comment: `%` suggests a `csh` shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%` is the C shell prompt. It's not universal for all shells. Depending on what kind of shell you're using, you could get a different kind of prompt when its waiting for your commands. For example UNIX shells commonly use the `$` sign and the Windows CMD prompt uses the current directory followed by a `>` character.

`vi` is simply a *shell command* which calls vi, a Unix-platform text editor. In your example, he's just using the text-editor vi to modify the Python script changer.py. It has nothing to do with Python other than the fact that the text editor can be used to edit Python scripts.

`python -mtimeit -s` is using the `-m` *command line argument* to load a module and then start the interpreter with the module `timeit` pre-loaded. That way you don't have to type `import <modulename>` after starting the interpreter. It is also using the `-s` command line argument to specify that the user-site-packages directory should not be added to `sys.path`.

For more information on command line arguments for the python interpreter, check out the [official documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html)

Comment: Perhaps you could mention that `% ` is the shell prompt, printed by the system, while `vi` is the command, typed by the user. It seems like the OP may be confused on that point -- he seems to think that he is supposed to type `% vi`.